# How to using `ORDER BY` to another table on `Oracle` database?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to using `ORDER BY` to another table on `Oracle` database?

I have 2 tables

**WA_BT_TBL_DESCRIPTION**

```
DESCRIPTIONID | DESCRIPTION | PROFILEID_FK | DATEADDED
F03           | First Step  | P001         | 10/3/2017 10:15:14 AM
F01           | Third Step  | P001         | 10/2/2017 9:11:32 AM
F02           | Second Step | P001         | 10/2/2017 9:11:32 AM
```

**WA_BT_TBL_DAY**

```
DESCRIPTIONID_FK | DAY | TIME  | PROFILEID_FK
F02              | Wed | 09:00 | P001
F03              | Wed | 09:15 | P001
F01              | Wed | 08:00 | P001
F02              | Thu | 09:00 | P001
F03              | Thu | 09:15 | P001
F01              | Thu | 08:00 | P001
```

I want to show description on table `WA_BT_TBL_DESCRIPTION` with `ORDER BY TIME ASC` on table `WA_BT_TBL_DAY`

Query so far:

```
SELECT
E.DESCRIPTIONID,
E.DESCRIPTION,
E.PROFILEID_FK,
D.DESCRIPTIONID_FK,
D.DAY,
D.TIME
FROM
WA_BT_TBL_DESCRIPTION E,
WA_BT_TBL_DAY D
WHERE
E.DESCRIPTIONID = D.DESCRIPTIONID_FK
ORDER BY D.TIME ASC
```

When I'm querying, it show me duplicate data.
What I want is description show not duplicate and order it by `TIME ASC`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you show the output to clarify what do you mean by duplicate data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DISTINCT` and `INNER` JOIN` together.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
E.DESCRIPTIONID,
E.DESCRIPTION,
E.PROFILEID_FK,
D.DAY,
D.TIME
FROM
WA_BT_TBL_DESCRIPTION E
INNER JOIN
WA_BT_TBL_DAY D
ON
E.DESCRIPTIONID = D.DESCRIPTIONID_FK
ORDER BY D.TIME ASC
```

Earlier, you were using cross join, which actually might have return all the combination between two table. Also, there is no point of adding both  `D.DESCRIPTIONID_FK,` and `E.DESCRIPTIONID` column in your `SELECT`, since both has same value. You should either use one of them.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is it possible to keep show description even there is not yet data inserted to WA_BT_TBL_DAY? Example I have new data "Fourth Step", but on WA_BT_TBL_DAY not yet inserted.

Comment: @HiDayurieDave Yes, it will be shown as NULL. Use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: @HiDayurieDave I mentioned use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join to achieve this,

```
SELECT
    E.DESCRIPTIONID,
    E.DESCRIPTION,
    E.PROFILEID_FK,
    D.DESCRIPTIONID_FK,
    D.DAY,
    D.TIME
FROM
    WA_BT_TBL_DAY D left join WA_BT_TBL_DESCRIPTION E 
    on d.DESCRIPTIONID_FK = e.DESCRIPTIONID 
ORDER BY D.TIME ASC
```